# Why $F_\mu V^\mu=0$ in special relativity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, forces, velocity

I'm trying to prove why
$F_\mu V^\mu=0$.

Where $F^\mu$ is the four force and  $V^\mu$  is the four velocity.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the four force $F$ on a particle of constant invariant mass $m$ is

$$F = m\, \mathrm{d}_\tau V\tag{1}$$

where $V$ is the four-velocity. Moreover, recall that the Minkowski norm of a four-velocity is unity (or $c$, more generally, in nonnatural units). So therefore we have

$$\mathrm{d}_\tau (V_\mu\,V^\mu) = 0 \tag{2}$$

as a universal identity. Now expand (2), use (1) and you should be able to prove your identity readily.

---

**Footnote** The Minkowski norm of the four velocity is constant because it is the length of a path between two infinitessimally displaced events $A,\, A+\mathrm{d} A$ divided by the proper time to traverse this path as measured by an observer moving along this path. But this latter quantity is of course the Minkowski length of the path, so we're dividing the length by the length, which is always unity.

Answer (score 2):

According to definition of 4-force:
$$F^{\mu}=m_0 \frac{d V^{\mu}}{d \tau}$$
$$\to F_{\mu}V^{\mu}=\eta_{\nu \mu}F^{\nu}V^{\mu}=m_0 \eta_{\nu \mu} \frac{d V^{\nu}}{d \tau} V^{\mu}=m_0\frac{d}{d\tau}(V^{\mu}V_{\mu})-m_0 \eta_{\nu \mu} \frac{d V^{\mu}}{d \tau} V^{\nu} $$
But we know that:
$$V^{\mu}V_{\mu}=c^2$$
and $\eta_{\nu \mu}$ is symmetric so:
$$m_0 \eta_{\nu \mu} \frac{d V^{\nu}}{d \tau} V^{\mu}=m_0 \eta_{\nu \mu} \frac{d V^{\mu}}{d \tau} V^{\nu}$$
So:
$$2m_0 \eta_{\nu \mu} \frac{d V^{\nu}}{d \tau} V^{\mu}=m_0\frac{d}{d\tau}(c^2)=0\to 2F_{\mu}V^{\mu}=0$$